# python programm to log into the web page

Tags: python

Does anyone knows what's wrong in this code ?
When I run it I get same HTML page back.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from http import cookiejar
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login = 'username'

password = 'password'
cookiejar = cookiejar.CookieJar()
urlOpener = \
    urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
urlOpener.addheaders = [('User-Agent',
                        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11 Linux i686)AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'
                        )]
values = {'user_name': login, 'user_pass': password, 'login': 'Login'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
binary_data = data.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request('http://securityoverride.com/login.php'
                                 , binary_data)
url1 = urlOpener.open(request)
url2  = urlOpener.open('http://securityoverride.org/challenges/programmin/1/index.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url2.read(), 'lxml')
print soup.find_all('center')
```

Comment: Indention and quotations are your problems here. Fix those and we may be able to help a little more.

Comment: Use requests instead of urllib. Requests is like a wrapper for urllib. It makes it a lot easier. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ I'm totally adicted to it :P

Comment: it's not possible using urllib

Comment: There’s also a CSRF token inserted at run-time. It has a quite useless/broken value but maybe the server checks for its presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       urllib.request
       import urllib.parse
       from http import cookiejar
       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

      url = "http://securityoverride.com/login.php"
      name = "username"
      passw = "password"

      def Login():
       cj = cookiejar.CookieJar()
       user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
       headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
       redirect =urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler()
       opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
       values = {'user_name': login, 'user_pass': password, 'login': 'Login'}
       data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
       binary_data = data.encode('utf-8')
       login = urllib.request.Request(url,binary_data,headers)
       login_response = opener.open(login)
       url2  = urlOpener.open('http://securityoverride.org/challenges/programmin/1/index.php')
       soup = BeautifulSoup(url2.read(), 'lxml')
       print soup.find_all('center')

Login()
```

Answer (score 0):

Login into a web applicaction by script may be trivial or awfully complex, depending on how the login page is organized. In my experience, the only foolproof way is :

- use a network spy like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)
- spy a full successful login sequence from a true browser
- until successful loop :

  - try to reproduce it with the script
  - spy the login sequence from the script and analyze differences

IMHO using `urllib2` or `requests` make little differences. The only tool that is much better at that would be `mechanize`, but unfortunately it seems not to be ported to Python 3